# Replace a word by a latex function using sed

Tags: bash, sed

I am trying to replace a 'word' in a file file.txt by the latex function defined in an array fun in bash script. As the latex function contains the backslash /, I tried | and @ in place of / in the sed command. But still it is not working properly. Can somebody help to figure out the problem?

```
#!/bin/bash

fun=('\sin^{5.4}(x)' '\cos^{6.5}(x)')

sed  "s@word@${fun[0]}@g" file.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: Also, I think you will need a double `\\` to pass it through all the way.

I don't know much about latex functions, but when I'm trying to work out quoting things, sometimes it pays to concatenate strings. Does this work? :

```
#!/bin/bash

fun=('\\sin^{5.4}(x)' '\\cos^{6.5}(x)')

sed  's@word@'"${fun[0]}"'@g' file.txt
```

Comment: No, it is not working. It is leaving the backslash from the \sin^{5.4}(x) in the output

Comment: I think you also will need a double `\\ `. Answer updated

Comment: Yeah, it is working. Thanks a lot. Can you please let me how is it so?

Comment: I believe when bash resolves the `${fun[0]}` part you end up with `sed 's@word@\sin^{5.4}(x)@g'`, but in a bash string, a `\ ` is used to escape special characters, so you need a double `\\ ` to get a literal backslash.